# Limits within Simpson's Paradox

Tags: statistics

I've been studying about Simpson's paradox, and encountered this question:
[image: Question]

Why must the positive value be less than 2.7%?

According to the explanation, people can move between groups, which generated a total increase of 0.8% across those years.

Imagine however one person in every group, except a million in the lowest level of 9th or lower. The income of the lowest level is 1\$ and the highest income is 100\$.

Now all of them except one switched to a Bachelor's degree, earning 97.3\$ - which is 2.7% less than that one person in year 2000. The total median change was therefore ~ 9700% higher, even though the net change in each group was lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your point looks correct to me.

In fact, you do not even need the numbers of people in each group to change.  For example with three people in each group before and after and these individual incomes:

```
           -----2000-----      -----2012-----     
<9th        500 1000 1500       500  963 4500
9-12       1500 2000 2500      1500 1866 4500
HS         2500 3000 3500      2500 2901 4500
At.coll.   3500 4000 4500      3500 3852 4500
AD         4500 5000 5500      4500 4500 5500
BD+        5500 6000 6500      5500 5838 6500
```

you would get the "changes in medians" for each row as stated but the overall medians would go from $3500$ to $4500$, i.e. an increase of over $28.7\%$, more than ten times the official answer for a top bound.  And it could easily be higher with different examples.

It looks like a bad question.